# Web Application Quality Metrics

Tags: web-application, metrics, standards

Is there a defined list of web application quality metrics?

I'm looking for a list of metrics like performance, reliability, usability, ... with a reliable source (w3c, ...).

I want to describe how a certain technology would improve nearly all aspects of web applications. For this, I need the list of aspects from a reliable and quotable source.

All I could find was the Web Quality Model ([Google Books](http://books.google.de/books?id=ctCQlhwJ9IUC&lpg=PA147&ots=B3NCoMIY3f&lr&hl=de&pg=PA149#v=onepage&q&f=false)) and [ISO/IEC 9126](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_9126)

Am I missing a relevant source? Or is the ISO the definitive guide?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no definitive guide without narrowing the context dramatically.

What you are searching for has no universally-accepted set of metrics. If you search for web quality metrics, you'll find millions of hits full of personal opinions, or what matters most to selected individuals.

If you are trying to promote your technology, the right thing would be to search to see what "aspects of web applications" matter to most people, and stress how your solution helps them. You get to pick the metrics you happen to like (or happen to be best at) and cite them as "important". That's what all vendors do.

Comment: The problem is, I don't want to promote, I want to rate the technology based on objective and reliable metrics, therefore I don't want to define them by myself, but learn and quote from an expert / book / consortium / standard.

Comment: Search for web quality metrics and you'll find hundreds, if not thousands. Pick the ones that you think are meaningful, then rate away. I suppose you could find a book by some "expert" who think certain metrics mean more than others ("web pages should load in less than 4 seconds"), but really, it's all about context, not universal metrics.

Comment: Perhaps these will help: http://www.e-valid.com/Technology/White.Papers/website.quality.html
"A WebSite is like any piece of software: no single, all-inclusive quality measure applies, and even multiple quality metrics may not apply."

http://www.w3c.it/papers/cmg2005Poland-quality.pdf

http://cibl-tcl.com/Documents/Research%20Papers/kk_Measuring_QMETR_WEBAPP.pdf

http://infocarnivore.com/looking-at-3-measures-and-metrics-for-website-quality/
"As a mathematician I hate to say it, but the best tool for evaluating a site is still the human eye."